# Select from customer or contact

Tags: sql

A table records the activities of customers and contacts, by their number.
I want to do a query that lists the name, whether it comes from the customer table or the contacts table.

Comment: Sounds like you might need a `union`, but there's not enough detail in the question to be sure.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images!). [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select cus.name from customers cus
union
select con.name from contacts con
```

or you could try:

```
select name from customers
union
select name from contacts
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union all`:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   customers
UNION ALL
SELECT name
FROM   contacts
```

If you want a distinct list of names, you could use `union` instead:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   customers
UNION
SELECT name
FROM   contacts
```